# How to find document through nested children id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, algorithm

I have nested children in my document i want find document any children._id
my document look like below.

For Example:

I want this children._id "PxX4EYMYVDOphx8XU" how to find this document.

```
[{
  "_id": "v4jdHchuogyumed7f",
  "name": "products",
  "children": [{
    "_id": "fDE1kyR081Y44aO7h",
    "name": "Clothes",
    "children": [{
      "_id": "l464EYMYVDOphx8XU",
      "name": "Shoes",
      "children": [{
        "_id": "PxX4EYMYVDOphx8XU",
        "name": "Black Shoes"
      }]
    }, {
      "_id": "gUHcdTuPxXhauIWaZ",
      "name": "Shirts"
    }]
  }, {
    "_id": "svcdrpPybHJf0KiBi",
    "name": "Flowers",
    "children": [{
      "_id": "gdEk85byoRCWxStTf",
      "name": "Red Flowers"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: i'm not use Array#findIndex,

Comment: you want the last child `_id` in the nested object.

Comment: Looks like you will need to recursively walk the object and test `_id`

Comment: No, any 'children._id` not depend on positions.

Comment: So all the `children._id` from the object.

Comment: yes `children._id` from the object

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: i'm not attempted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively walk the object and match `_id` then return the parent object. An example could be.

```js
var walk = returnExports;
var x = [{
  "_id": "v4jdHchuogyumed7f",
  "name": "products",
  "children": [{
    "_id": "fDE1kyR081Y44aO7h",
    "name": "Clothes",
    "children": [{
      "_id": "l464EYMYVDOphx8XU",
      "name": "Shoes",
      "children": [{
        "_id": "PxX4EYMYVDOphx8XU",
        "name": "Black Shoes"
      }]
    }, {
      "_id": "gUHcdTuPxXhauIWaZ",
      "name": "Shirts"
    }]
  }, {
    "_id": "svcdrpPybHJf0KiBi",
    "name": "Flowers",
    "children": [{
      "_id": "gdEk85byoRCWxStTf",
      "name": "Red Flowers"
    }]
  }]
}];
var find = 'PxX4EYMYVDOphx8XU';
var children;
var parent;
walk(x, Object.keys, function(value, prop, object, depth) {
  if (prop === 'children' && Array.isArray(value)) {
    children = value;
    walk.STOP;
  }
  if (prop === '_id' && value === find) {
    parent = children.find(function(obj) {
      return object._id === find;
    });
    return walk.BREAK;
  }
});
console.log(parent);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/Xotic750/object-walk-x/master/lib/object-walk-x.js"></script>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-walk-x if you don't want to write your own object walker.